# Is there a Android POS full node wallet apps that is open source? An app that can also stake?

Tags: android, proof-of-stake, open-source

Are there any Android Proof of Stake apps that is open source. The peercoin app seems to be a light client. Some of the apps seem to be QT transformed to Android.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is no, there isn't an Android full node app. Being a full node would requiring downloading and storing the entire block chain, and that is too much data for mobile devices.

I don't know of any mobile wallets that stake. And you are right that many of the apps are just the QT code transformed to Java. I think it was done this way on purpose so as to ensure that the two references are bug-for-bug compatible.